# Flask React TS app gets 404 Error on Submit

Tags: reactjs, flask, curl, proxy

I am trying to build my first Flask React TS app.

I set up my project using Vite React TS.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
react-flask-app
|-backend/
|---|-app.py
|-frontend/
|---|-node_module/
|---|-public/
|---|-src/
|------|-App.css
|------|-App.tsx
|------|-index.css
|------|-main.tsx
|------|-vite-env.d.ts
|---|-index.html
|---|-package-lock.json
|---|-package.json
|---|-tsconfig.son
|---|-tsconfig.node.json
|---node-module/
```

my `backend/app.py` file looks like the following, and I run it by calling `flask run` from the `backend` directory:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome to the Flask backend!'


@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    data = request.form
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    print(f"Received data: Username - {username}, Password - {password}")

    return "Data received successfully!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My `fontend/src/App.tsx` looks like the following, and I run `npm run dev` from the `frontend` directory:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await axios.post('/signup', { username, password });
      console.log('Request sent successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred while sending the request:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And my `frontend/package.json` file contains the follow at the top of the file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
....
```

When I send the curl request `curl -X POST -d "username=Jennetta&password=George" http://localhost:5000/signup` I get the response
`Data received successfully!`, telling me that my backend API is working as expected. But when I visit 192.168.40.30:5173:3000/signup (or localhost:3000/signup) and enter username/password and hit submit, I get the error:

```
App.tsx? [sm]:15 Error occurred while sending the request: AxiosError
handleSubmit @ App.tsx? [sm]:15
xhr.js:251          POST http://192.168.40.30:5173/signup 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:251
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:148
httpMethod @ Axios.js:187
wrap @ bind.js:5
handleSubmit @ App.tsx? [sm]:12
callCallback2 @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
```

When I look at my network for `/signup`, it shows a request URL of http://192.168.40.30:5173/signup (or localhost:5173/signup, depending on whether I use local or network access). My intuition is telling me that this is the error, shouldn't it be giving a network request url of localhost:5000/signup? I already put the proxy:localhost:5000 in my package.json file.

Please let me know if there is any other information you need. I've spent the past 2 hours debugging with GPT4, and it has not been able to figure it out.

Comment: I feel fairly certain that this is a proxy issue, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to fix it. Everything is correct according to documentation, but it is sending requests to localhost:5173/api instead of localhost:5000/api

Answer (score 0):

After reading through every article on how to fix this issue, and none of them working - I finally realized that I already had something running on port 5000, so by simply changing the port that flask was using from 5000 to 8080, and by feeding axios the hardcoded "http://localhost:8080/signup", the problem was solved!